# problem while adding cisco iosv

Tags: virtualbox, cisco

I am trying to add Cisco IOS v to GNs3 2.1.11.

I followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dWxiLiXbLIc , but always I got this error:
[image]

I already installed GNS3VM with Virtualbox and it's already working and as shown :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone will or had faced the same problem, I had found the answer and I will post it below:

> > Every QEMU, VirtualBox and VMware node in GNS3 runs as a virtual machine. Some node types like IOSv need hardware-assisted
> >     virtualization, for QEMU this is called KVM (Kernel-based Virtual
> >     Machine). As the GNS3 VM itself is a virtual machine, your system
> >     needs nested virtualization. That means it must support hardware
> >     assisted virtualization of the QEMU VM (here IOSv) within a virtual
> >     machine (the GNS3 VM).
>
> For that you need the right hardware. Your CPU must support VT-x on
>   Intel CPUs or AMD-V on AMD processors. Furthermore the virtualization
>   software must support nested virtualization. Until lately VMware was
>   the only software, that supports that. With VirtualBox v6.0 nested
>   virtualization is supported on AMD processors.
>
> If you happen to own a system with AMD processor, see
>   https://youtu.be/bZKTRIF7UJg how to configure VirtualBox to support
>   nested virtualization. If your system uses an Intel processor, you
>   have to use VMware Workstation or Player to run the GNS3 VM. It's
>   currently not possible to use IOSv with VirtualBox on Intel
>   processors.

[image]